# Moodle - Redirect on /<a></a> after an update on admin panel

Tags: php, moodle

I have a Moodle application version 4.0.2 over Apache webserver, using PHP v8.0. After a login as administrator or submitting a change into administration panel, the application will redirects you on a really weird URI like "example.com/admin/<a></a>".

I searched a lot in order to fix this behaviour, someone said it's a permission problem, so I changed the entire data directory and application directory to "0777" as reported into the official documentation. Someone else said it's an Apache misconfiguration. That's it:

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>
  ServerName example.com
  Redirect / https://example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:443>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/httpdocs
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

  AcceptPathInfo On

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certificates/certificate
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certificates/certificate

  <Directory /var/www/example.com/httpdocs/>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Taking a deep look on what the application does, it seems like to return a 303 after a login/submit that brings you on the page [https://example.com/admin/\](https://example.com/admin/%5C)</a>.

This stuff is driving me crazy, because I do not have any error or info log, neither an useful output from Apache itself.

Answer (score 2):

After a long session of debugging, I figured out who put the  element into the URL. There is a [core library from Moodle](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/lib/weblib.php#L2892), weblib.php, that has a function `redirect`. This function does a set of string operations on the URL where you want to navigate, such as replacements and sanitizing. Now, if you take a look to [this specific line](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/lib/weblib.php#L2990), this lib execute a replacement on `clean_text('<a href="'.$encodedurl.'" />', FORMAT_HTML)` pattern, from `/^.*href="([^"]*)".*$/` to `\\1` - according to [preg_replace function documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) -. Printing out the output of this line, it return `<a></a>`, that is an argument of the function `redirect()` on each index.php script on every package. Commented this line, will make everything work like a charm and, moreover, improve a lot the performance.

I'm not too much happy to make updates into Moodle's libraries. You know, they should be ready to use "as is".